# Modifing text on active stage in business process flow

Tags: dynamics-crm

The active stage on a business process flow always has additional text like (Active for 3 days, 4 hours). Is it possible to modify this text / prevent it from showing?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer, but as far as I know: No.

Answer (score 1):

May be too early to ask for such configuration from Microsoft :)

This is just loading from default inbuilt template to show state code/status code + timer like Active or Abandoned for x hours/minutes,etc

Impossible at this point of time to change/hide the text, Unless you want to do some unsupported customizations like exploring DOM & touch the innerHTML.

Comment: I will not mark it as anwser since it is not a sollution. But thank you for explenation